# Read an XPUB list of transactions to Python using my own node

Tags: python

Anyone familiar with a Python library that can get a list of all transactions under an XPUB but by connecting to a Bitcoin node through RPC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something [like this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/83804/how-to-get-the-derived-public-key-from-xpub) might be a lead for what you're after.  It gives you a list of addresses which you can then query your node by RPC.

You then use the [getbalance RPC method](http://chainquery.com/bitcoin-api/getbalance).  People I know use the python [slickrpc package](https://github.com/barjomet/slick-bitcoinrpc) from [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/slick-bitcoinrpc/).

Comment: Just to follow-up and document my findings. After some research, I've decided to leverage the Open Source project from [Samourai Dojo](https://github.com/Samourai-Wallet/samourai-dojo). 
Tracking wallet balances via xpub requires conforming to BIP44, BIP49 or BIP84 address derivation scheme and the Dojo can do that through a local node.